# Customizing Workbox to handle inactive globPatterns?

Tags: workbox

Workbox throws the following error when a glob pattern cannot find any matching files:

```
Error: One of the glob patterns doesn't match any files. Please remove or fix the following: {
  "globDirectory": "public/",
  "globPattern": "dist/dep/**/*.{js,css}",
  ...
}
```

In some cases, it might be expected for a directory to be empty (e.g. during a dev build files are not minified bc it takes a fair amount of time). An env argument could likely be used as a workaround, but it would be great if Workbox could gracefully fail when no files are found.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend doing is structuring your build configuration to use some state information about the environment (like `NODE_ENV`) to either include or remove `globPatterns` as needed.

You don't mention whether this is for webpack, the CLI, or otherwise, but here's an example:

```
const globPatterns = NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
  ['**/*.{html,js,css}'] :
  [];

GenerateSW({
  // Other config.
  globPatterns,
})
```